# Selenium Export test cases as PHP-phpunit is missing in my Selenium IDE 1.2.0?

Tags: php, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I really in need of converting/exporting my test cases to PHP. But PHP-phpunit formatter in Selenium IDE 1.2.0 is missing. Can you please tell me how can I get it? Its really urgent please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP formatter has been [removed starting in IDE 1.2.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes#1.2.0)0, presumably because nobody was maintaining it.  You can either [go back to IDE 1.1.0](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/1.1.0/selenium-ide-1.1.0.xpi) and never upgrade, or you can try the [PHP formatter from 1.0.2](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/formatters/php/1.0.2/php-format-1.0.2.xpi), which might work.  Long term, you've got a decision to make about what language you're going to use instead of PHP.

Comment: `Long term, you've got a decision to make about what language you're going to use instead of PHP`. Even when seen in it's historical context this answer is funny. Did you really thought, that guys are switching to another programming language just to have the selenium exporter? Why shouldn't they just write that exporter? (You see, they did ;)

Comment: -1 due to statement `you've got a decision to make about what language you're going to use instead of PHP`. No I'm not big fan of PHP but still we can't support such bold statements just because we do not like/understand a thing.

Comment: @KapilSharma The comment had nothing to do with not liking or understanding a thing.  I understand PHP very well, and I have no opinion either way about it.  The comment had everything to do with the fact that nobody had been willing to step up and support and enhance the PHP formatter for a long time.  That's how Open Source works - if you care about a thing, you work on it, and if you don't, you don't.  As hek2mgl pointed out, someone did indeed step up.

Answer (score 23):

Great news - it's been revived! https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-php-formatters/

Thanks to Dan Chan for taking that on.

Comment: Yes, by installing "Selenium IDE: PHP formatters" plugin you can meet your purpose.